# Partition the set $\{1,2,\ldots, 2n\}$ into $n$ subsets of size 2, such that each pair differs by 1 or $n$.

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

Encountered this problem in a textbook - find the number of ways to partition the set $\{1,2,\ldots, 2n\}$ into $n$ subsets of size 2, such that each pair differs by 1 or $n$. I wasn't too sure how to proceed - initially, I tried to count all the ways to partition $2n$ elements into $n$ subsets of size 2, and subtract the cases that don't differ by 1 or $n$. This proved to be very tedious/basically impossible to calculate. Any ideas?

Comment: One **idea** that may or may not help is to consider only the elements $~\{1,2,\cdots,n\}~$ and ask yourself: in how many ways can these elements be formed into $~k~$ pairs, where $~2k \leq n.~$  Any element $~x~$ not partnered in such a fashion will get partnered with $~(x+n).~$  The question is: does this capture all of the possible satisfactory pairings?  Do the $~\{n+1,\cdots,2n\}~$ pairings with each other have to perfectly parallel the corresponding $~\{1,2,\cdots,n\}~$ pairings with each other?

Comment: Assuming that you pursue the approach in the previous comment, think of $~\{1,2,\cdots,n\}~$ as prisoners on a chain gang, chained into groups, where each group must have an even number of prisoners (with consecutive numbers) chained together, and there are unchained prisoners.  This may be challenging to convert into a Stars and Bars inequality.  You have groups containing an even number of *prisoners* chained together, with $~1~$ or more unchained prisoners between each chained group.

Comment: Pursuing the previous comment, it seems that you are looking for the number of non-negative integer solutions to $x_1 + 2y_1 + x_2 + 2y_2 + \cdots + x_k + 2y_k + x_{k+1} = n,~$ where all variables except $~x_1,x_{k+1}~$ must be $~\geq 1,~$ and where $~k~$ can be any number $~\geq 0~$ such that $~2k + (k-1) \leq n.$

Answer (score 9):

Imagine a $2 \times n$ rectangular grid, filled with the numbers $\{1,2,...2n\}$ as shown below:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-1 & n \\
\hline
n+1 & n+2 & n+3 & \cdots & 2n-1 & 2n \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Notice that numbers that differ by $n$ are vertically aligned. Thus the subsets being chosen have to consist of either a horizontally adjacent or vertically adjacent pair. The problem then is akin (almost! see note at the end) to tiling a $2 \times n$ rectangular grid with dominoes; this is a well-known problem for which the solutions are the Fibonacci numbers.

Seeing why this is the case is easy by induction. Let the number of tilings for a $2 \times n$ rectangle be $t_n$. Clearly when $n=1$ and $n=2$, there are only one and two ways to tile the rectangle, respectively; so $t_1 = 1$ and $t_2 = 2$.

Now take a $2 \times n$ rectangle, $n>2$, and consider the rightmost squares. They can only be covered two ways, either with one vertical domino or two horizontal dominoes. In the former case, the remaining $2 \times (n-1)$ rectangle can, by the induction hypothesis, be covered in $t_{n-1}$ ways; and in the latter, the remaining $2 \times (n-2)$ rectangle can, by the induction hypothesis, be covered in $t_{n-2}$ ways. So $t_n = t_{n-1} + t_{n-2}$. Combining this with the base cases proves $t_n = F_n$ (if you start at $F_{\small 0} = 1$) or $F_{n+1}$ (if you start at $F_{\small 0} = 0$).

**However**, there is one situation (thanks @Zoe H for noticing) that is not covered by the rectangular grid scenario. If $n$ is odd, it is possible for $n$ and $n+1$ to be paired; luckily (and this is easy to see by checking the grid) this forces **all** pairs to be ones that differ by $1$, so it only adds a single additional case (except when $n = 1$, for which they're the same)(thanks @BrianHopkins).

Thus the final answer is: $F_1$ when $n=1$, $F_n$, if $n$ is even, and $F_n+1$, if $n \ge 3$ is odd.

Comment: +1 (also) : much more elegant than the Stars and Bars approach considered in my comments, following the original posting.

Comment: There is a solution where each odd number $k$ is be paired with $k+1$. If $n$ is odd then one of the pairs is $\{n, n+1\}$, so this solution doesn't correspond to a tiling. I think this is the only solution your method misses, because if we remove the squares $n$ and $n+1$, then we are forced to use horizontal dominoes to tile the rest of the grid and only works if $n-1$ is even.

Comment: @ZoeH Great note, thanks; this did occur to me when I first considered the problem but I completely forgot about it when I thought of the rectangle idea, will adapt my solution

Comment: I think it's $F_n+1$ for $n \ge 3$ odd since there's only 1 solution for $n = 1$ (i.e., where the vertical pair and the wrap-around horizontal pair are equivalent).  Without that exception, the sequence 2, 2, 4, 5, 9, 13, 22, 34, 45, 89 is in the OEIS as [A127968](https://oeis.org/A127968).

Comment: @BrianHopkins Yup, absolutely right, thanks; will edit (again!)